# DNS Server isn't responding

Tags: home-networking

This connection works DSL modem+windows 7 machine =web access ok.

DSL modem+Wireless Router+ windows 7 machine=no web access "DNS server isn't responding"

I have tried a different Wireless Router  but same result.
This was a working system ,went to work came home and family reports it just stopped working,

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Either this switch isn't actually a switch or there is a computer on the switch that is intercepting DNS requests.

Can you list the Make and model of the Ethernet switch?

Also, is there other computers on the Ethernet switch?

Comment: WBR-1310 Wireless G Router. ActionTec GT701D. Copper Connection from modem to WAN port on WBR-1310. Copper connection from port 1 of WBR-1310 to windows 7 machine. There are currently no other computers connected. Prior to problems I had 3 laptops via wireless. But now none work.

Comment: I'm not sure about that model. Try resetting it.http://support.dlink.com/emulators/wbr2310/support_tools.htm